# Play 2.2.1 Injecting into other classes than controller

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dependency-injection, playframework-2.2

I followed this excellent example https://github.com/huntc/play-spring-data-jpa to include JPA and DI into Java Play application. It works great, but in more complex applications it's harder to implement few things.

Major problem is using DI with:

- plugins (for example Deadbolt, where in Deadbolt handler you need to access database to retrieve user and roles).
- forms (in validate method you need to authenticate user)

My question is: how to inject repositories (or anything else) into other classes except controller? I have tried accessing repository with Play.current().global().getControllerInstance(PersonRepository.class); but I find this hackish. Any ideas how to solve it OR must I choose another approach?

Comment: Your DI framework should handle this.

Comment: Can you provide an example?